# How to turn this attr_writer attribute into an actual database column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this *Post* model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_names
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

  attr_writer :tag_names
  after_save :assign_tags
  before_create :init_sort_column

  def tag_names
    @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(" ")
  end

  private

  def assign_tags
    self.tags = []
    return if @tag_names.blank?
    @tag_names.split(" ").each do |name|
      tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      self.tags << tag unless tags.include?(tag)
    end
  end

  def init_sort_column
    self.content_changed_at = self.created_at || Time.now
  end
end
```

and *Tag* model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_users, :source => :user, :through => :subscriptions

  def tag_posts_count
    "#{self.name} (#{self.posts.count})"
  end
end
```

I would like to turn `attr_writer :tag_names` into an actual column in the database so I can do this: `Post.find_by_tag_names("drinks")`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think of turning around the associations?

`Tag.find_by_name('drinks').posts`

You should archive the same.